# Apache Forward Proxy With SSL Termination

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

I'm trying to set up an Apache Forward Proxy that terminates the SSL connection. The reason I'm trying to do this is to run Apache filters (specifically [mod_pagespeed](https://www.modpagespeed.com/)) on the returned code. Before I deal with mod_pagespeed, I'm testing this POC by trying to insert a header into the response (which will prove that I can edit the response), but I'm having issues with SSL proxying (non-SSL proxying works fine).

Note that I'm not concerned about any certificate errors or the like -- this is purely for internal testing.

I've got the server set up and see the X-MSCProxy Header on a non-SSL page:

```
jshannon-macbookpro:pagespeed_proxy jshannon$ curl -vv --proxy pagespeed_proxy:3ja82ad9@localhost:8080 -D - -o /dev/null http://www.slate.com

* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'pagespeed_proxy'
> GET http://www.slate.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.slate.com
...
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2017 18:10:40 GMT
Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2017 18:10:40 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
...
< Content-Length: 187051
Content-Length: 187051
...
< X-Instart-Request-ID: 8286987369135064135:FWP01-NPPRY22:1509387040:0
X-Instart-Request-ID: 8286987369135064135:FWP01-NPPRY22:1509387040:0
< Via: 1.1 172.17.0.2:8080
Via: 1.1 172.17.0.2:8080
< X-MSCProxy: SansPS
X-MSCProxy: SansPS
```

But when I make the same request to Slate's SSL page I don't see my proxy:

```
jshannon-macbookpro:pagespeed_proxy jshannon$ curl -vv --proxy pagespeed_proxy:3ja82ad9@localhost:8080 -D - -o /dev/null https://www.slate.com

* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.slate.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'pagespeed_proxy'
> CONNECT www.slate.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.slate.com:443

< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-agent: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Proxy-agent: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
< 

* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: ssl004.insnw.net
* Server certificate: GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3
* Server certificate: GlobalSign Root CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.slate.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 

< Content-Length: 187044
Content-Length: 187044
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
< X-Instart-Request-ID: 762420041708891440:FWP01-NPPRY21:1509387251:0
X-Instart-Request-ID: 762420041708891440:FWP01-NPPRY21:1509387251:0
```

I've found a lot of posts that say this is possible (and, technically, it should be) with various httpd.conf suggestions, but nothing I've tried has worked. Right now my httpd.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyVia On

  Header set X-MSCProxy SansPS

  #SSLEngine On
  # suggestion that this allows termination
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key

  ModPagespeed Off
</VirtualHost>
```

FWIW, when I enable SSLEngine on this proxy (as has been suggested) then the request simply doesn't work with this error from Apache:

```
[Mon Oct 30 18:20:20.705047 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 372:tid 140147985901312] [client 172.17.0.1:34012] AH01996: SSL handshake failed: HTTP spoken on HTTPS port; trying to send HTML error page
[Mon Oct 30 18:20:20.705107 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 372:tid 140147985901312] SSL Library Error: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request -- speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
```

Which I guess makes sense as the proxy protocol isn't expecting an HTTPS connection directly to the proxy.

Comment: It's not possible with any typical client for a pair of reasons.

1) https clients don't talk to foward proxies over SSL, as you saw.

2) Even if your client used https to the proxy, it would still use https
through the established CONNECT tunnel so the proxy wouldn't be able to see
HTTP requests/responses through it to manipulation.

Seems like a dead end to me.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: How about not using it as a proxy but using a host file to point the domain to apache server and then proxy passing the request to the original sever? This works because you will have a `https (domain IP changed using host file)-> Apache -> https on original site`

Comment: @TarunLalwani. Hmm. Are you suggesting I'd then write my own proxy (which could be easy: `return curl(request_url)`). Your approach would take advantage of the hosts file to not have to deal with rewriting links, assets, and XHR requests (which is useful).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the output filter feautre fom apache.

https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration#apache_specific

> AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html

Comment: How would that solve the issues with being able to terminate the SSL proxying? Without termination (ie, if Apache is simply passing through the request via a CONNECT command) then modules are completely unable to filter.

Comment: Because you want to use mod_pagespeed you can try to use the filter. I don't know why you want to create the mitm solution maybe just for pagespeed that the reason for my suggestion for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `https://` to the curl proxy command like this:

```
jshannon-macbookpro:pagespeed_proxy jshannon$ curl -vv --proxy https://pagespeed_proxy:3ja82ad9@localhost:8080 -D - -o /dev/null https://www.slate.com
```

Apache complained about connecting to port 8080 with http even though https is configured for this port.